# Ruby: how to parse txt in xls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, csv, xls

I am a newcomer in Ruby and I want to parse txt file(new7.txt)
The sample of input txt file is:

```
Revision: 37407
Author: imakarov
Date: 21 June 2013 г. 10:23:28
Message:
update specification from Jhon (it was in VTBSOATST-1219)
----
Added : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/BR-5610 Публикация клиентских данных в АБС Бисквит (CifOraSyncOffPers).docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/BR-5610 Публикация клиентских данных в АБС Бисквит.docx

Revision: 37406
Author: imakarov
Date: 21 June 2013 г. 10:22:16
Message: 
delete files

----
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ с замечаниями Кочебина С..docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ-comments.docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ-comments_Орлов.docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ.docx

Revision: 37405
Author: dboytsov
Date: 21 June 2013 г. 10:21:17
Message:
add attributes in file
----
Modified : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5864 Запрос данных клиента по интернет-анкете КН/Преобразование BR-5864.docx
Modified : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5864 Запрос данных клиента по интернет-анкете КН/ЧТЗ BR-5864 Запрос данных клиента по интернет анкете.docx
```

The colleagues from Stackoverflow helps me with programm:

```
require 'csv'
data = []
File.foreach("new7.txt") do |line|
  line.chomp!
  if line =~ /Revision/
    data.push [line]
  elsif line =~ /Author/
    if data.last and not data.last[1]
      data.last[1] = line
    else
      data.push [nil, line]
    end
  elsif line =~ /Date/
    if data.last and not data.last[2]
      data.last[2] = line
    else
      data.push [nil, nil, line]
    end
  end
end

CSV.open('new1.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  data.each do |record|
    csv << record
  end
end
```

But now I have the following situatuion:
[image]

And I need that:
[image]

I use an export in .csv
May be it would be a better way to export in .xls ? Is it a difficult to export in .xls file in each column inside?
I have such words in input file (new7.txt) as "Revision" "Author" "date" and so on. In input file it is not a column. And I want to parse the input file and copy to .xls by columns

Comment: I'm not sure why you got all data in one column. If you saved the converted data in a CSV file (as the script did), Excel should parse them into three columns automatically. If there are problems, you can still use `Data` -> `Text to Columns` menu to split the data into columns separated by `,`.

Comment: @ArieShaw Thank you!!! It's a real help me!!! I am a shamed that I don't know this function of Excel before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your regional settings (only US seems different) Excel should use semicolon (";") as CSV separator instead of coma (",").

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> *"Microsoft Excel will open .csv files, but depending on the system's regional settings, it may expect a semicolon as a separator instead of a comma, since in some languages the comma is used as the decimal separator."*

You can use option `:col_sep` to specify a column separator.
This should works.

```
CSV.generate('new1.csv', 'w', {col_sep: ";"}) do |csv|
  data.each do |record|
    csv << record
  end
end
```